# Is there a way to open Customize Format window of intl.cpl control panel?

Tags: .net, windows, command-line-interface, control-panel

As seen below, **Customize format** window is brought up by pressing `Additional settings...` button in **Region** control panel which can be open using command `control intl.cpl`.

Is there a way to programmaticaly open **Customize Format** window?
(Even a workaround counts.)

My goal: Send user from my application settings directly to place where they can view/customize accepted digit format (comma, thousands separator etc.). Allows users to learn that there are centralized Windows settings for this.

It looks like this primary [MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191(VS.85).aspx) for opening control panels forgot about **Region** control panel at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible workaround I can think of is by programmatically listing child controls of of **Region** control panel window and then identifying and pressing **Additional Settings** button. Doesn't look like easy task, but doable, as seen at screen with readers accessibility software.

Comment: You may have noticed that the control panel has been redesigned in Windows 10, so this technique may not work for much longer.